# How to make Postfix use PostgreSQL for relay information and accepted domains

Tags: postgresql, postfix-mta

I am building a mail filtering appliance using CentOS 7, Postfix and MailScanner.

I have installed Postfix from the CentOS Plus repo, so that it could be installed with support for PostgreSQL.

However, I am having some trouble with figuring out how to make Postfix read information from the database and also which tables should be present.

I have the following table already created on database running on a PostgreSQL 10.1 server:

```
field          type
id             uuid
name           varchar(128)
destination    varchar(128)
relay_type     varchar(64)
created        timestamptz
updated        timestamptz
active         bool
```

The basic idea would be to fill the table with the domains and destinations as needed for the email accounts hosted on internal servers and my lab environment.

```
name          destination              relay_type   active
domain.com    mailserver.domain.com    smtp         1
domain.xyz    somewhere.domain.xyz     smtp         1
notme.io      notsend.notme.io         smtp         0
```

The condition for when to actually accept email for the domain and relay to the destination would be represented by this SQL statement:

```
SELECT 1 FROM domains where name = '%s' and active = 1
```

Then to determine the destination, I would need to combine the values of the `destination` and `relay_type` columns using this statement:

```
SELECT relay_type + ':' + destination AS transport FROM domains WHERE name = '%s' AND active = 1
```

The actual issue is that I cannot figure out what to modify in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to get postfix to actually read from the database using the above queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use proxy lookups in your main.cf

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
```

Then in the file you need the information on how to do the lookup, mine is mysql, so you'll have to use the postgresql setup, but this is just an example.

```
user = postfixadmin
password = postfixadmin
hosts = localhost
dbname = postfixadmin
query = SELECT domain FROM domain WHERE domain='%s' AND active = '1'
```

http://www.postfix.org/PGSQL_README.html

Comment: Adding `proxy:` got me at little further. Now it says `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table`. I have tried with `virtual_alias_domains`, `virtual_alias_maps`. When using `virtual_mailbox_domains` it gives `4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)`. I think that this requires me to add `virtual_transport = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-transport.cf` with the previously listed query `SELECT relay_type + ':' + destination AS transport FROM domains WHERE name = '%s' AND active = 1
` or am I wrong?

Comment: What transport are you planning to use?  dovecot-lda or lmtp? something else?  It sounds like you have a lot to do.  I used the below walkthrough when setting up postfixadmin with mysql backend.  https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/set-up-a-mail-server-with-postfixadmin-and-mariadb-on-centos-7/

Comment: Actually it is a bit more complicated, as I will need to deliver using `smtp` to different internal hosts, so that this appliance acts as an edge device for the incoming emails, which are then processed here before being sent to the actual mail servers. This way, I also remove the load of bouncing non-existent domains or addresses. I will look at the link to see if it helps me further

Comment: You'll need transport maps on your domains to determine where to relay them.  The traditional way is in the /etc/postifx/transport_maps file with a format like `domain.com  smtp:[mx.domain.com]:25`

Comment: So returning that directly from SQL should make the same?

Comment: You need to query for the domain, and then return the transport method.  Below is an example query from mysql `query = SELECT concat('relay:',description) FROM domain WHERE domain='%s' and transport = 'relay' and active = 1`  The description field is where you would put the hostname of the next server and the port if needed.

Comment: It looks like in your case with the fields you have defined, the query would need to be something like - `query = SELECT CONCAT(relay_type,':[',destination,']') from domains where name='%s' and active = '1';` You need the brackets around the destination so that postfix will use the A record you give, otherwise postfix will assume it needs to lookup the MX for the record you gave.

Comment: I tried both versions of the query and now it seems to accept everything, but it does not relay to the destination host. Could be something with either the destination host configuration or something with the `MailScanner` configuration

Comment: Did you setup the database proxy under `transport_maps` in the main.cf?

Comment: I have not set it as `transport_maps`, but as `virtual_transport = proxymap:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-transport.cf`. As I recall the postfix config, this is required when we have virtual domains